# Ajax call to action with a List of KeyValuePairs as parameter

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I wish to simply do an AJAX call to a method expecting a List of Key and value pairs, but I have no idea how to do this. I tried the following:

Server method:

```
UpdateBranches(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> brancheItems)
```

data to be send:

```
 var brancheItems = [];
 businessActivities.forEach(f =>   
     brancheItems.push({
      Key: f.sbiCode,
      Value: f.sbiCodeDescription
 })
```

This seemed to give me an array of objects with key and value properties. (network tab showed it), but it did not work. I also tried to make an array of objects with one property (propertyname is the key, value is the value):

```
for (var itemIndex in items[index].businessActivities) {
   var key = items[index].businessActivities[itemIndex].sbiCode;
   brancheItems.push({ 
key: items[index].businessActivities[itemIndex].sbiCodeDescription
        });
    }
```

Note that on the server I seem to receive an array/list of 3 items with two properties, but the properties are always empty. Does anyone know the correct format for the data to be send

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply create your object like this:

```
var ParamtersContainer = new Object();
ParamtersContainer = {
    "PatientName": 'Alameer',
    "ServiceDate": '12/12/2017',
    "ProviderName": 'ahmed'
};
```

Then make it as data parameter in your ajax request, receive it as a dictionary in your c# action.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data:JSON.stringify( {brancheItems: brancheItems}),
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Succeded");
        }
    });
```

And use the [bracket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) notation:

Instead of `brancheItems.push({ key : value });` 
use

```
var object = {}; 
object[key] = value;
brancheItems.push(object);
```

Comment: There's no need specifying the contentType 
> contentType: "application/json"

Comment: I said 'something like this.'